# Session variable lost after $_Post in php

Tags: php, session, post

I have session variable at the begining but it is lost after I clicked the button. Here is my code, $_SESSION['InputCount'] is not null and true at the begining but after I clicked the button I can't reach session variable. $iteration variable in the isset block is null. Also I have a sesion variable that holds userid in it from previous page, it has no problem It is still true. What is wrong with $iteration?

```
<?php

require("includes/db.php");
require("includes/functions.php");

session_start();  

$inputCount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputCount']);
$_SESSION['InputCount'] = $inputCount;   //it is ok at the begining

//check if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['checkoutButton'])){

    $iteration = $_SESSION['InputCount'];
    var_dump ($iteration);

    $userID = $_SESSION['UserID'];
```

Comment: Why is there a second `session_start` at the end of your code?

Comment: Your current code simply means `$iteration = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputCount']);`: Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: *"but after I clicked the button"* - What button? Show us the full code and how it's being used.

Comment: sorry, there is no second session_start in my code. It is my misteke when copy paste it. I edited my post. So @Hanky웃Panky, yes I need that

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is checkoutButton, you see the code run after I clicked it  (isset part)

Comment: Question is, is the button "named"?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  here is the button code                            <div>
 <button type="submit" id="checkoutButton" name="checkoutButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Siparişi Bitir</button>
                            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of $_POST['inputCount'] is being assigned to your session variable regardless of how the page is loaded.

In other words, when you post back using the checkout button, rather than pulling the value of inputCount from the session, you're overwriting the value based on the current $_POST['inputCount'], and then reading that from the session (which is redundant).

What you probably want is something like this:

```
require("includes/db.php");
require("includes/functions.php");

session_start();  

//check if the form has been submitted
if(!isset($_POST['checkoutButton'])){
    $inputCount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputCount']);
    $_SESSION['InputCount'] = $inputCount;   //it is ok at the begining
} else {
    $iteration = $_SESSION['InputCount'];
    var_dump ($iteration);

    $userID = $_SESSION['UserID'];
}
```